# Style sheet for XML not rendering in IE9

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet

I have a xml document which right now is not even recognized as xml on IE9. I have tried adding correct xmlns:xsl attribute, also it has a correct header starting with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This xml renders perfectly in IE 6 7 8 but does not work in IE9.
I am not sure if it is Quirks mode related issue, and if it is I am not sure what DOCTYPE is should use for XML documents. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Following is the first few lines of XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/mobiledoc/jsp/empi/master/CCD.xsl" ?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" 
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd" 
                  classCode="DOCCLIN" 
                  moodCode="EVN">
```

Comment: Consider to post a URL where we can visit the problem. Or consider to post enough information allowing us to reproduce the problem, in particular minimal but complete samples of XSLT and XML and details as to how the XML is served to the browser, whether over HTTP, which Content-Type the XML is served with.

Comment: If you need more information then ask about it, why down vote the post get going?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Martin I tried to post the XML in SO but I did not find an "attach" option here. I cant copy and paste the XML because it's huge. I do not have a web server where I can host it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Answer to your other question is, yest it's served over HTTP through a JSP. The content type is text/xml, I will post more code soon

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have uploaded the file at cynosuredev.com/CCDTest.xml By pasting the URL in IE you will see that it renders perfectly in any version < ie-9, including compatibility view. We tried DOCTYPE tag in different ways which does not seem to fix the issue. Other peculiarity that we observed was that we had to rename the XSL file to ".txt" for it to work. If we keep the extension to "XSL" then the browser complains about not being able to find the resource on the network!!

Comment: why are people downvoting my post even when it is answered and I believe it has all the info needed.... C'mon guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific as to how it's "is not even recognized as xml on IE9"? Do you get an error message, or is it simply that it looks different in IE9 than in previous versions?

The first thing your XML file does is associate itself with an XSLT stylesheet at "/mobiledoc/jsp/empi/master/CCD.xsl" so this could be the source of your problem. Some suggestions:

- As a test, remove the `<?xml-stylesheet .. ?>` bit. Do you now get the same behaviour in all browsers? (Probably just a hierarchical view of the XML file) If so, then the problem is in your XSLT stylesheet.
- What does that stylesheet do? If it's converting the XML file into HTML, it might be using some non-conformant (X)HTML constructs or styles which older versions of IE tolerated, but which IE9 is more strict about. If the "not recognized" is some layout/display issue, tweaking the stylesheet might fix what you see in the browser.

Based on what you've told us so far, I think that's probably where you need to start.

ETA: The upshot of the conversation below was that the `<xsl:output>` directive was forcing a 4.01 HTML doctype into the output; changing this to `<xsl:output method="html"/>` (and fixing a couple of other issues with the transform) fixed the problem in IE9.

Comment: "Not recognized" means that xml opens up as text(All text no tags) in the browser. Neither it renders the style nor does it show the XML hierarchy like IE does. Yes, we are converting the XML to in HTML, assuming the second point you made is the case is there a way to make IE9 less strict?

Comment: Apparently, IE9 doesn't process XSL on a remote server, though it looks as if you have a relative link to the xsl so it should be okay. The fact that it displays as nothing but text does sound as if it's trying to process the XML with a stylesheet, otherwise you'd see the tags. Without seeing the code, all I can suggest is testing the same XML with a very basic XSL stylesheet and then rebuild the stylesheet gradually to see which bit breaks the IE9 display (or whether you can get it to work at all).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have uploaded the file at http://cynosuredev.com/CCDTest.xml By pasting the URL you will see that it renders perfectly in any version < ie-9, including compatibility view. We tried DOCTYPE tag in different ways which does not seem to fix the issue. Other peculiarity that we observed was that we had to rename the XSL file to ".txt" for it to work. If we keep the extension to "XSL" then the browser complains about not being able to find the resource on the network!!

Comment: Thanks. There's an error in the stylesheet: you need to move the variable `patientRole` to the top of the `n1:ClinicalDocument` template. This isn't the cause of your IE9 problem, but it caused errors in Oxygen XML editor and Firefox on my machine. You also need to save the stylesheet with an XSL extension. This works on my machine with IE9 and XAMPP so it should be fine. Anyway, after that, I managed to make it work in IE9 by amending the `<xsl:output>` line at the top of the stylesheet so it just reads `<xsl:output method="html"/>` - I now see a table with blue and red headings in IE9. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I am glad that the issue was fixed - in this particular case that is.
But the real reason for the error in IE9 is not disclosed yet, so I will do that here.

**The reason for the encountered behavior is a bug in XSLT processing in IE9**.

Well OK - it's not really a bug, just bad error reporting. The point is that IE9 applies MSXML6 by default, and a lot of things have changed with respect to MSXML4. When there's a plain error in the XSLT, it's not reported - IE9 seemingly skips processing onto default text() templates, which results in presenting all text nodes.
Worse, when something is done in the XSLT that is prohibited by default in MSXML6, the same thing happens. So what's prohibited by default in MSXML6? A lot! Applying Jscript for instance. And DTD's. And the document() function won't work.

In the case above, one might suspect from the text shown (which obviously comes from applying the default templates), that there is an error in the xslt - waiting to be discovered with good tools. But this IE9 behavior is not so obviously linked to the xslt when there's no text in the xml part of the file opened (that is, when the xslt itself supplies all the data to be processed, for instance by importing xml files on runtime, or the data in the xml that the xslt processes is all in attributes and nodenames). You just have to know...

You can see the error message behind all this yourself if you go to developer tools by pressing F12 (or select it from the Tools menu). In developer tools subscreen, select Script Menu and load your page now. You will see that on the right, in the console, an error message appears:
`XSLT8690: XSLT processing failed.`
When this error occurs, only the text nodes in the xml are displayed (so, for an empty xml root node, the page will be blank).
I could find only one reference to this error on the web: http://www.wikistep.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4140.

Note that when you select "compatibility view" by clicking the torn page button next to the refresh button (which is not always available, another -minor- IE9 bug), the page goes back to IE8 display, and will be OK again - well, apart from any errors in xslt of course, but MSXML 4.0 does not have all these restrictions that MSXML 6.0 has by default. It's safer, for sure, but very annoying too.

Note that by selecting compatibility view, the site part of the file's url is added to the list of sites for which compatibility view is automatically applied.
To recreate the issue, you will have to remove the site from that list, by pressing Alt to open up the menu, selecting tools/compatibility view settings, and removing the site from the list before trying again.
Also note that the trick of applying compatibility view does not always fix things: when for instance the xslt calls embedded javascript containing classes not available in IE8 Jscript version, the xslt will fail in compatibility view too.

Now what can be done about this? Actually I am not sure - worth another question on SO!
The properties which are off by default can be switched on - but the examples I have seen only do so when loading an XML type string in a DOM object within a sequence of statements - and then one can assign the new DOM object the necessary properties before loading the string.
Here, IE9 takes care of loading the XML automatically and also loads the XSLT to process the XML. So where the hell can we set the XML load properties before the loading takes place?
I am sure it will take time - but I will find out!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using xslt function ex `document('../_data/nav.xml')/page:nav | document('http://www.ok.kz/_data/nav.xml')/page:nav` and if it points to another server it won't render your document, with no explanation, just blank page or xml as text